# MonoGame: Disable mouse input on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, monogame

I'm developing a monogame game app for several plattforms including Android, iOS and Windows Universal. Therefore I want to support touch as well as mouse input.

Problem is that on Android the initial mouse position is at (0,0) and is triggering a hover effect inside of the app which is not supposed to happen. Is there a way to disable Mouse input for android? On iOS I just set the mouse position out of the Viewport to (-1,-1). Which is hacky but it works. Unfortunately on Android `Mouse.SetPostion()` is not working for some reason.

Any other idea how to make the mouse disappear in MonoGame for Android?

Comment: This could be a bug in MonoGame. I'd go check the issues on github.